# Como insertar una imagen en un <p:menubar>

Tags: xml, primefaces, xhtml

podrían ayudarme con este problema que lleva un rato molestándome, he investigado mucho y no he podido solucionar este problema de insertar una imagen dentro de mi barra de menú, les comparto la imagen de como se ve la barra en este momento y el código, se lo agradecería si me ayudan.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya pude resolverlo abajo dejo el codigo resuelto saludos...

```html
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


    <h:form>
        
        <p:menubar  style="background: #333; width: 100%;">
            <p:menuitem>
                <h:graphicImage value="/imgs/Slidenew1.png" style="margin-left: 10px; position: fixed !important;  position: relative;" width="50px" height="70px"></h:graphicImage>
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="SIANSA" icon="ui-icon-person" style="width: 110px; color: #fff; position: relative;">
                <p:menuitem value="Perfil" url="#" icon="ui-icon-person" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Registro de Usuarios" action="#{buttonView.registroUsuarios}" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" style="color: black;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Salir" action="#{buttonView.buttonExit}" style="color: black;" icon="ui-icon-closethick" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>          
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Estilos" action="#{buttonView.segmentoEstilos}" style="color: white;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Clases" style="color: white;"></p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="Consultas" icon="ui-icon-help" style="width: 125px; color: #CCCCCC;">
                <p:menuitem value="General" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Estilos" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Clases" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" icon="ui-icon-home" style="color: whitesmoke; float: right;" ajax="false" ></p:menuitem>
        </p:menubar> 
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

**codigo resuelto**[image: Imagen de La barra ya acomodada]

```html
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- Barra de Navegacion   -->
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar  style="background: #333; width: 1185px; height: 30px;">
            <p:menuitem>
                <h:graphicImage value="/imgs/Slidenew1.png" style="margin-left: 10px; " width="50px" height="70px"></h:graphicImage>
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="SIANSA" icon="ui-icon-person" style="width: 110px; color: #fff;">
                <p:menuitem value="Perfil" url="#" icon="ui-icon-person" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Registro de Usuarios" action="#{buttonView.registroUsuarios}" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" style="color: black;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Salir" action="#{buttonView.buttonExit}" style="color: black;" icon="ui-icon-closethick" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>          
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Estilos" action="#{buttonView.segmentoEstilos}" style="color: white;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Clases" style="color: white;"></p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="Consultas" icon="ui-icon-help" style="width: 125px; color: #CCCCCC;">
                <p:menuitem value="General" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Estilos" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Clases" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" icon="ui-icon-home" style="color: whitesmoke; float: right;" ajax="false" ></p:menuitem>
        </p:menubar> 
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Si resolviste el problema, ponlo en la sección de respuestas de abajo en lugar de editar la pregunta. Stack Overflow no funciona como un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) y cada cosa debería ir en su sitio. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información y dime si necesitas ayuda con algo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Primefaces tiene una etiqueta para agregar contenido personalizado en la barra de menú.

```
<p:menubar>
    //submenus and menuitems
    <f:facet name="options">
        //custom content
    </f:facet>
</p:menubar>
```

¿Es lo que buscas?

También podrías agregar la imágen como un elemento del menú:

```
<p:menuitem>
    <h:link outcome="#">
        <h:graphicImage name="/miImagen.jpg"/>
    </h:link>
</p:menuitem>
```

Comment: bueno es que como se muestra en la imagen el menuitem se enésima en la imagen y quisiera solo recorrer esos textos a la izquierda solo un poco pero no encuentro como.

Comment: ¿Intentaste ponerlo como un elemento del menú? Eso hace exáctamente lo que necesitas.

Comment: si, eso hice y ahí en el código esta pero como la posicion que necesito ponerle a la imagen es fixed la acomoda perfecto pero me enésima el menuitem y eso que la imagen también esta como parte del menú.

Comment: Elimina el inline css y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo, era una cosa de nada, pero aquí les comparto el código por si alguien mas llega a tener el problema, gracias @GabrielMolina